# How to keep ListBox display updated during .Add calls

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get a smoothly scrolling list box that would behave the way Delphi's TMemo.Add() method.

Using the test code below, it scrolls fine for a while, and then pauses at about 600 and fails to refresh until done.

I've seen references to having to run the code below on a different thread for updating to succeed.  This is the kind of thing I use regularly and I'm hoping for a more simple solution.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(i);
            listBox1.SetSelected(listBox1.Items.Count - 1, true);
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
            this.Refresh(); // overkill but just to make sure...
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend doing that as the performance cost of continual redraw will really kill the speed, which is what you are seeing at about 600 - it's just getting too much for it to handle.

You can call `Application.Refresh` during the loop to keep processing the window messages, which keeps it responding but once again at the cost of performance.

A strategy I've seen recently, which is not simple but is effective is to fake the listbox. So during the adding, you hide the listbox and replace it with a panel or similar which you use to draw on something that looks like the listbox. When done you swop back. This way you get very smooth, and potentially more visually appealing effects. More work but maybe worth it.

Answer (score 0):

i haven't used application.refresh in a loop like this (though it may work perfectly well),  you might want to try application.processMessages. i have used that and it works for me.
-don

Answer (score 0):

You might want to think about this differently. I assume that you want the list box redrawn each time you add an item to show to the user that you're making progress. If this is the case, then the approach I use in similar situations is to:

1. Call BeginUpdate on the control
2. Do the work in a different thread
3. Make callbacks to the UI thread to add an item and update a progress bar. If your work is of indeterminate length, then run the Progressbar in Marquee mode at step 1.
4. When finished, callback to the UI thread to indicate that the work is done and therefore a call to EndUpdate should be made.

Answer (score 0):

On my computer it runs fine, until I try to interact with the form, at which point it will stop updating. But, that's not the point. The real question is, why would you want to fill a list box with 10000 items and have it updated for every item that is displayed?

One reasonable option could be to batch up items (perhaps in a separate thread) and then post a number of items to show every now and then:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
        {
            List<int> ints = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                ints.Add(i);
                if (i % 25 == 0)  // update the listbox on every 25th item
                {
                    this.Invoke(
                          new Action<IEnumerable<int>>(AddItemsToList), ints);
                    ints.Clear();
                }
                if (ints.Count != 0)  // make sure to add any "trailing" items
                {
                    this.Invoke(
                          new Action<IEnumerable<int>>(AddItemsToList), ints);
                }
            }
        });
}

private void AddItemsToList(IEnumerable<int> items)
{
    listBox1.BeginUpdate();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
    listBox1.EndUpdate();
    listBox1.SetSelected(listBox1.Items.Count - 1, true); 
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
    listBox1.Update();
}
```

And now you also have a fairly responsive UI while the list is loading.